# android paid and free app

Tags: android, package, release

Can one android application source code i.e. one package name be used for free and paid app with the only difference in the source to be a flag ? Like:

```
boolean APP_FREE = true;//for free verions
boolean APP_FREE = false;//non-for free verions
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

All you need is a different package name. You don't even need an arbitrary boolean flag. You **must** have a different package name though.